# Drawing exactly $r$ red, $g$ yellow and $b$ blue balls out of an urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In an urn, let there be $U \in \mathbb{N}$ balls. Of these balls, $R$ are red, $G$ are yellow and $B$ are blue, and there are no other colors than these in the urn. (So, $R + G + B = U$.) Now, without putting them back, we draw $u ≤ U$ balls out of the urn, and we are now interested in the probability that we draw exactly $r$ red, $g$ yellow and $b$ blue ones (with $r, g, b \in \mathbb{N}_0$).

First, I want to find this probabilty $p := p(r, g, b, R, G, B)$, as just described.
Next, I want to find the limit of the probability as we let $U$ go against $\infty$, and with $\frac{R}{U}, \frac{G}{U}$ and $\frac{B}{U}$ converging against constants $p_1, p_2, p_3 \in \mathbb{R}_{≥0}$.

Now I first thought about solving the "trivial" cases. If $r > R, g > G$ or $b > B$, then we have $p = 0$. Same goes if $r + g + b ≠ u$. But I haven't come much further than that.

I know that if we were just interested in getting an exact number of balls of only *one* kind of color (and the remaining ones being unimportant), e.g. if we only demanded getting exactly $r$ red ones, then I could apply the formula for the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), which describes this exact scenario. But I'm only intested in the case where the numbers of *all* kinds of balls I draw are determined, i.e. where I don't only demand $r$ red ones, but also exactly $g$ yellow ones and $b$ blue ones. Can I somehow iterate or modify the $HyG$ formula to match this new scenario?

I'm or course open to any other kinds of solutions aswell; I just thought the $HyG$ formula would be a good way to approach it. Thanks in advance.

(What I'm asking doesn't sound like an extremely unusual or rare problem to me, so if it has already been answered somewhere, I'd also appreciate it if I'm being linked to it. When I searched for it with roughly the words I used in the title, I couldn't find this very scenario.)

Comment: Is $r+g+b=u$? @moran

Comment: I didn't have $r + g + b = u$ as a requirement, but since there are no balls with other colors than these three, we have that the probability must be $p = 0$ if $r + g + b ≠ u$. So the only "interesting" case is if $r + g + b = u$, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

> where I don't only demand $r$ red ones, but also exactly $g$ yellow ones and $b$ blue ones. Can I somehow iterate or modify the $HyG$ formula to match this new scenario?

Yes.    You want the probability of drawing $r$ from $R$ red, $g$ from $G$ <s>green</s> yellow, and $b$ from $B$ blue, out of all the ways to draw any $r+b+g$ from all $R+G+B$ balls.$$\dfrac{\dbinom{R}{r}\dbinom G g\dbinom B b}{\dbinom{R+G+B}{r+g+b}}\quad=\quad\dfrac{\dbinom{R}{r}\dbinom G g\dbinom B {u-r-g}}{\dbinom{U}{u}}$$

Sensible?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, yes. That actually much simpler than I expected. I will see if I manage to work out the second part with the limits using that formula.

Comment: I might add, intuitively it seems like the limit of the probability should be $0$ if we let $U \to \infty$, and $R, G, B$ as described in the question. I guess that I could work that out by inserting the definition of the binomial coefficient into the formula and simplifying it, until the limit is visible... but is there maybe an easier way to figure out the limit? (I'm gonna try the other way nevertheless..)